# Query with two different sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I want to have the same query with data from two different sheets. I've done this:

```
=sort(QUERY({Sheet1!$C:$I;Sheet!2$C:$I},"select C ,count (F) where F<>"" group by C order by C desc),2,false)
```

But I get this error message:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: C
```

Does anyone how to do it?The error doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

with `{}` you are creating a new range which does not have any sheet coordinates per se (how would you query `{Sheet1!$C:$I;Sheet!2$D:$J}` for example?

You can refer to the columns by index, try:

```
=sort(QUERY(
  {Sheet1!$C:$I;Sheet!2$C:$I},
  "SELECT Col1 ,count(Col4) where Col4 <> "" group by Col1 order by Col1 desc), 
  2, false)
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. It works and now I know how it works :)

Comment: If this helped you please accept the answer, thanks :)